# Install gem from forked git - looks like it's installed ok but it's not in gem list and and i can't require it

Tags: github, rubygems, bundle, bundler

Sorry if this is a duplicate, i've seen a couple of questions about bundler and git but don't quite get it.

I forked a gem that's on github - my fork is `https://github.com/toastkid/contentapi-ruby`

In my Gemfile, i changed the gem line to use the :git option, pointing at my new fork:

`gem "guardian-content", :git => "git://github.com/toastkid/contentapi-ruby.git"`

I then did

`bundle update guardian-content`, and it said

`Using guardian-content (0.2.2) from git://github.com/toastkid/contentapi-ruby.git (at master)`

I thought that meant that i would now have the gem installed, but i don't: it's not in `gem list`, and i can't require the gem in a ruby console.

I read that github doesn't do gem hosting any more.  I'm not 100% on what that actually means (gem hosting as opposed to hosting the source code for the gem?).  So, i cloned my fork down to my machine, and built it on there.  Then, i changed the line in Gemfile to point to the local folder containing the gemspec file:

`gem "guardian-content", :path => './gems/contentapi-ruby'`

I then did

`bundle update guardian-content`

again, and this time it said

`Using guardian-content (0.2.2) from source at ./gems/contentapi-ruby`

Still no guardian-content gem in `gem list`, still can't require it.

Can anyone set me straight?  How can i use my forked (ideal), or locally built (If necessary), gem in bundle install?  I'm going to be deploying this to my server so need to get it working in a reliable way.

thanks, max

Answer (score 3):

Using gems from git (or from the local filesystem with :path) in Bundler doesn't install them to your GEM_HOME, so they're not available to RubyGems in the usual way, but it does make them available to Bundler as long as they're in the Gemfile.

If you want to include the gem in irb, make sure the Gemfile and Gemfile.lock are in the current directory and (in irb) do this:

```
require `bundler/setup'
require 'guardian-content'
```

Depending on your version of Ruby/RubyGems (and your $RUBYOPT) you may have to `require 'rubygems'` before you `require 'bundler/setup'`

Comment: Thanks to stevenh512 for pointing this out, exactly what I was looking for.

As reference, http://gembundler.com/git.html